# Convert String (FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF) into int array java

Tags: java, android, hashmap, hex, type-conversion

I'm parsing an XML file with some entries like this one:
 `<control key="test">FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF</control>`

I save them into a `HashMap` and now I want to convert the `String` that I get into an `int[]`.

But I'm not sure how to do it. 
I tried to parse it with this: `Interger.parseInt(mEntry.getValue().toString(), 16);`, but it failed with error `NumberFormatExceptoin: Invalid int: "FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF"`

I googled my problem but did not find any solution for my problem.
Is there anything to get this done? Maybe to saved it already in the `Hashmap` as an `int[]`

Here the code for parsing:

```
public static Map<String, String> paramListConf1(Context c, int listResID) {
    Map<String, String> map = null;
    XmlResourceParser parser = c.getResources().getXml(listResID);

    String key = "", value = "";

    try {
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (parser.getName().equals("map")) {
                    boolean isLinked = parser.getAttributeBooleanValue(
                            null, "linked", false);

                    map = isLinked ? new LinkedHashMap<String, String>()
                            : new HashMap<String, String>();
                } else if (parser.getName().equals("windowcontrol")) {
                    key = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "key");

                    if (null == key) {
                        parser.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                if (null != key) {
                    value = parser.getText();
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getName().equals("windowcontrol")) {
                    map.put(key, value);
                    key = null;
                    value = null;
                }
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return map;
}
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<map linked="false">
    <message>
        <window>
        <control key="test1">FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF</control >
        <control key="test2">EE EE EE EE EE EE EE EE</control >
        <control key="test3">DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD</control >
        <control key="test4">00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00</control >         
        </window>

</message>
</map>
```

and the implementation:

```
public void getXMLResourceInput() {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Map keyMap = ResourceUtils.paramListConf1(WindowControlActivity.this, R.xml.config1);

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Iterator iter = keyMap.entrySet().iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
        Integer.parseInt(mEntry.getValue().toString, 16);
    }
}
```

Comment: to an array of ints, link `int[] test = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };`

Comment: It looks to me like your trying to parse an integer from the entire string. The spaces account for the format exception you get. I assume you want to get 'FF' as an integer, in an array with 8 elements (all FF from your example). To do so, split the string on spaces to get an array of strings where each index holds "FF". Construct an int[] of the same size, and parse the individual elements out and parse as you are currently, storing each value in the int[] at the corresponding index.

Comment: So splitting seems to be the only thing to do. I know that this would be possible, but I thought there is maybe an easier way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want the String "FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF" as an array of ints and not as an single int, because its to big for int and -1 as long.

```
    String hexString = "FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF"; 
    String[] hexNumbers = hexString.split(" ");   //split the string
    int[] ints = new int[hexNumbers.length];      

    for(int i = 0; i<hexNumbers.length; i++) {
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(hexNumbers[i], 16);  //convert from hexString to int
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<ints.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(ints[i]);
    }
```

Output: 255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255

There are two reasons for your **NumberFormatException**. First there are whitespaces in the String and secound, if you remove them it is "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" much bigger than 2^31-1 (max size of an positive int).

Comment: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF may be the in memory representation of -1. Right? System.out.println(Long.toHexString(-1L)); // ffffffffffffffff

Comment: that looks great, will try it out immediately

Comment: You think its even possible to do that in my parsing method, so I can write the int[] into the hashmap (after I made a Map<String,int[]>)?

Comment: to your edit: I get this exception on every Hexstring, also on `00 24 23 04 fa 32 23 99`

Comment: yes because 00 24 23 04 fa 32 23 99 is still bigger than an int and there are whitespaces.

Comment: ah okay, sorry, but I misunderstood this

Comment: did it worked now? And yes you can definetly do that in your parsing method and store the arrays you get in the map.

Comment: Can't really say if it works, cause I'm getting a NPE :) Have to solve this problem and then I can give you an answer :)

Comment: @user270349 you are right, ffffffffffffffff is -1 when you try to store it in a long variable, becuase the sign bit changed to 1

Comment: @kai I mean FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF might be a valid long from certain point of view. I don't know if it is the case.

Comment: ah okay you are right, but i think Fraggles dont want FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF to be represented as -1. but you are right, i will change it. but if you try to parse it: Long.parseLong("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16); you will still  get a NumberFormatException

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because of the spaces between FF bytes. They are supposed to be `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` 
This is going to fix it: `Integer.parseInt(mEntry.getValue().toString().replaceAll("\\s+",""), 16);`

Comment: no positive result, crashes with the same NumberFormatException